# Looking for emigration records from Liverpool England in 1921

Tags: england, 1910s, canada, emigration

I have an arrival record for my wife's grandmother.

She and her mother/brother/sister arrived in Halifax, Canada on the "SS Canada" in February 1921. The record said that the ship departed from Liverpool, England.

I'm trying to find the departure records from Liverpool. I found the FamilySearch collection [Departures from the Liverpool Office 1914-1923](https://www.familysearch.org/search/film/008087187?cat=344960), but so far I haven't found the SS Canada in that collection.

Any ideas on where I can find the departure information? I'm hoping that I can find where (in Poland) they came from originally, and possibly find her father, who probably came the same way a couple of years previously.

Comment: Ancestry have this collection UK, Outward Passenger Lists, 1890-1960 that may help it has over 23 million records in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ancestry has a [Collection of UK Outward Passenger Lists 1890-1960](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/ukoutwardpassengerlists/) which include "Transmigrants" departures from Liverpool in 1921, including the SS Canada. You can search by departure year and place and ship name.  [Findmypast](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/search-world-records/passenger-lists-leaving-uk-1890-1960) has the same dataset.  If you don't have a subscription to Ancestry it's worth looking out for 'free weekends'.

It's very likely that when you find your ancestors, the passenger list will show that they entered England at Hull (from where they would have got a train to Liverpool to travel onward across the Atlantic). The list will usually show the ship they arrived in at Hull.

Arrivals in England from Europe were not usually recorded according to [the National Archives](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/passengers/):

> UK passenger lists do not record travel within Europe unless a ship called at more than one European port before travelling further afield.

so your next step will be to look for the passenger list on departure of the ship that brought them to Hull.

Comment: Thanks! I found them in the outward Passenger lists. It says that they came from Poland (natch), entered the UK at "Dover" on the ship "Belgian Mail Packet". Now to figure out how to backtrack *that*.

Comment: @MarshallClow I believe the Belgian Mail Packet departed from Ostend.

Comment: http://arch.arch.be/index.php?l=en might help @MarshallClow

Comment: Also https://avotaynuonline.com/2015/08/utilizing-belgian-archives-for-jewish-genealogical-research/

Comment: Reply from the Belgian Archives (arch.arch.be): "The National Archives of Belgium conserves no passengers lists."  (@ColeValleyGirl: This is not a complaint about your comment above, but rather a note for future readers)

Comment: @MarshallClow Write a new Q and I'll take a crack at it.  First thing I'd look for is to see what companies ran those 'mail packet' ships. Newspaper research would probably turn that up if you don't have any clues in your passenger list.

Comment: @JanMurphy: Done: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/acestors-came-to-england-on-the-belgian-mail-packet-in-1920-1921-how-to-find (Thanks!)

Comment: @MarshallClow Good to see you've raised a question about locating the passenger records, but I also think you should review the other link I provided (which talks about locating records for temporary alien residents in Belgium) as another line of attack..

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - I'm working on that too, but I see two things that make it harder; (1) many of the records have 100 year seals on them - which will expire in a couple of years, and (2) My wife's ancestors were not Jewish.  Still, I'm working on them.

Comment: @MarshallClow I understand your persons of interest might not be jewish but many of the same techniques and recordsets will apply.  The closure issue is a bit more challenging :)