# Ancestors came to England on the "Belgian Mail Packet" in 1920/1921 - How to find those records?

Tags: england, immigration, belgium

My wife's grandmother (Annie Pieniążek, age 9) emigrated from Poland to Canada in the early 1920s. She travelled from Liverpool to Halifax on the "SS Canada", leaving 10-Feb-1921, and arriving 19-Feb. From there she went on to Winnipeg, where she lived the rest of her life.

I've found the Canadian arrival records, and the Liverpool departure records. The Liverpool departure records say that they (her mother, brother, Annie, and sister) came from Poland (natch) and arrived in Dover on the "Belgian Mail Packet"

How can I find records about that service?  I've contacted the Belgian National Archives (arch.arch.be) and they said: "The National Archives of Belgium conserves no passengers lists."

Comment: They probably arrived on *a* Belgian Mail Packet, which appears to describe the ship's role. Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_boat) "Packet boats were medium-sized boats designed for domestic mail, passenger, and freight transportation in European countries and their colonies". I've seen some references to the Belgian Mail Packet Offices, 53 Gracechurch-street, London, and it might be worth finding out what happened to that organisation. From searching the BNA, it looks like by ~1910 the main mail route was Dover-Ostend.

Comment: There's a bit of general information about the mail packets here: http://www.timetableimages.com/maritime/images/rmt.htm